# adding data to sqlAlchemy after uploading Files to flask from multiple different Ajax requests

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I've two set of files being uploaded at the same time with by the same function via Ajax let's call the

1- set `A` which only upload single file at a time. - Url: `/upload1`

2- set `B` which include multiple files per request. - Url: `/upload2`

`A = {id=id , file1=file1 }`

`B = {id=id , file2=file2 }`

Then I've List of names of set `B` ready to be uploaded as well

the files were uploaded fine each set in a different upload function

the problem occurs when i'm trying to commit them to the database because each function expects 3 values and i only provide 2 the only way around it was something like this

```
class Files(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  code = db.Column(db.String(255))
  file1 = db.Column(db.String(255))
  file2 = db.Column(db.String(255))



  def __init__(self,id,code,file1,file2):
      self.id = id
      self.code = code
      self.file1 = file1
      self.file2 = file2



@app.route("/upload1" ,methods = ["POST"] )
def upload1():
    importedFiles = request.files.to_dict();
    for file in importedFiles:
        file1 = importedFiles[file].filename

        file2 = ""
        addFiles = Files(id=id ,file1=file1 ,file2=file2 )
        db.session.add(addFiles)
        db.session.commit()
    return '', 204


@app.route("/upload2" ,methods = ["POST"] )
def upload2():
    importedFiles = request.files.to_dict();
    for file in importedFiles:
        file2 = importedFiles[file].filename

        file1 = ""
        addFiles = Files(id=id ,file1=file1 ,file2=file2 )
        db.session.add(addFiles)
        db.session.commit()
    return '', 204
```

so i had to mention the messing variable and give it a value `fileX = ""` which will results in **overwriting** each other every-time any of those functions run.

so the end result should have value for `file1` and `file2` , how can i do this without ***overwriting*** each other in the ***database*** ?

is there's a way to send **both set of file requests** to the **same url** and run some sort of if statement to **define which is which** ? 
- I've used `FormData.append('file', FileData, FileName)`method before **Ajax**

*( that will fix my problem as i can store both values in two different variables and commit them together in the same commit request)*

Comment: So what is the question exactly?

Comment: @Joost as i've mentioned i don't want to over write the value everytime i run any of the functions that uploads the set of files. i need them to add up on each other in one way or another.

Comment: Are you perhaps asking how to perform an update, or merge?

Comment: @IljaEverilä yes that sounds right